# Replace text between two markers

Tags: ansible

I'm doing a ansible-playbook which should replace the text between 2 markers/strigs however I'm not able to do it.

```yaml
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
  - name: insert/update configuration using a local file and validate it
    blockinfile:
            block: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/$USER/tmp/ssh_keys.template') }}"
            dest: "/home/$USER/tmp/ssh_keys"
            marker: "xidiot"
            marker_begin: "##### "
            marker_end "##### "
```

I need file content of ssh_keys.template to replace the block of text in ssh_keys file between markers (which are present in ssh_key file):

```
##### xidiot START
```

and

```
##### xidiot END
```

After running this playbook the content of ssh_keys.template is placed on the bottom of the file ssh_keys.

Here's the block which is inserted after the end marker "##### xidiot END":

```
 xidiot
### xidiot ADM
key 1
key 2
key 3
### xidiot ADM END

### xidiot OPS
key 4
key 5
key 6
### xidiot OPS END

### xidiot AUTOMATION BEGIN
key 7
key 8
key 9
### xidiot AUTOMATION END

### OTHERS
key 10
key 11
key 12
### OTHERS END
 xidiot
```

Note that xidiot in the beginning and in the end are not presented in the template file. The template file begins with ##### xidiot START
If I delete the marker, marker_begin and marker_end from the .yml file and place

```
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK

# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

in the ssh_keys file instead of

```
##### xidiot
```

Everything is working as expected.

And here's the template itself:

```
##### xidiot START
### xidiot ADM
key 1
key 2
key 3
### xidiot ADM END

### xidiot OPS
key 4
key 5
key 6
### xidiot OPS END

### xidiot AUTOMATION BEGIN
key 7
key 8
key 9
### xidiot AUTOMATION END

### OTHERS
key 10
key 11
key 12
### OTHERS END
##### xidiot END
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to include the output you are getting in practice, and any error messages you are seeing. That will make it easier for the community to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html) carefully about `{mark}` placeholder.

Comment: If you are using a jinja2 template, why not just update the block using jinja2?

Comment: Thank you guys, I've edit my original question.
@Konstantin Suvorov I've read it carefully but obviously I'm not understanding it correctly or something is not working as expected.

Comment: @2ps, I can only use ansible. And...a custom script with sed. However I prefer Ansible, it's way more clear, tidy and etc.

Comment: @xidiot:  jinja2 is part of (well technically a dependency of) ansible:  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_templating.html

Comment: @2ps, thank you for pointing that. However it seems that I cannot figure it out.

Comment: @xidiot:  if you're comfortable posting your `ssh_keys.template` file, I can help you out

Comment: @2pc, I've put it in the description. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a variable with the keys instead of a separate file and loop over them using [`with_subelements`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-subelements).

```
---
- set_fact:
    keys:
      - name: user1
        keys:
          - key1
          - key2
          - key3
      - name: user2
        keys: 
          - key4
          - key5
          - key6

- name: update authorized keys
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.0.name }}"
    key: "{{ item.1 }}"
    state: present
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ keys }}"
    - keys
```